# os.sytem('exit') is not working as intended in my code

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to install node.js and then check appium version using `appium -v`

```
import os,subprocess
os.system('node.msi')
os.system('exit')
os.system('appium -v')
```

`node.msi` is a node file on my computer. when i do it through cmd, `appium -v` works if i do it in a new cmd, but it doesn't work if i keep using the same cmd. so i was hoping that after exit, my code should have worked. can someone point out what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Each `system` call spawns a new `cmd.exe` anyhow, so it makes zero sense to do `system('exit')`.

Comment: Then how come if i manually write 'appium -v'' in a new cmd,  it works? but not here

Comment: Because the shell actively monitors the registry keys that are used to initialize the environment variables and update its environment variables accordingly, while any other process just keeps what it got at startup. You can spawn all the processes you want from your Python script, but its environment will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the installation of node.msi modifies your system's `PATH` variable. This change does not become visible inside your running Python process.

If you know the path to your node installation, you can specify it explicitly in a call such as

```
subprocess.run([r'C:\node\bin\apium.exe', '-v'])
```

Comment: appium checks version of appium which needed node.msi to be installed. however installing node doesn't give me any appium.exe file

Comment: So what's the path to appium, and is it part of your PATH?

Comment: appium doesn't set any path in the environment variable

Comment: So what is the path to the appium exe, then?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running Windows here. When a *console* starts, it reads its environment from the registry. That explains why it works when you open a second cmd *console*.

That means that you have to ask Python to lauch the command `appium - v` in a new console (and not only a new `cmd.exe` shell).

It can be done through `os.system` by using `start`:

```
os.system("start /W appium -v")
```

or depending on what is really `appium`:

```
os.system("start /W cmd /c appium -v")
```

You could also directly use the subprocess module (which offer more configuration than `os.system`)

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cmd / c appium -v", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
p.wait()
```

Depending on what appium is, the following could be enough:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("appium -v", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
p.wait()
```

Comment: Its still not working. I even tried using the complete path. I want to point that if i use the previous cmd to open the new cmd and write appium -v, it still doesnt work. to make it word i need to open cmd from start all over again